# Comparing Docker Tags

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Given that I build and tag an image like so:

```
docker build -t foo:bar .
docker tag foo:bar foo:baz
```

How can I. later, confirm whether or not the two tags refer to the same thing? I would like to be able to do this through the Registry API (v2), since I might not have both images locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (tedious?) way of doing that includes comparing the `fsLayers` registered in the manifest file attached to each tag:

Download http://your-registry/v2/repo/image/manifests/tag1 and http://your-registry/v2/repo/image/manifests/tag2:

```
{
    "name": "repo/image",
    "tag": "tag1",
    "architecture": "amd64",
    "fsLayers": [{
        "blobSum": "sha256:d7958e841d1f103cc24e45cb6108eaf09ecf0b424f071ac6b6ab39241cec293d"
    }, {
        "blobSum": "sha256:d7958e841d1f103cc24e45cb6108eaf09ecf0b424f071ac6b6ab39241cec293d"
    }, {
        "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
    }],
    "history": [
        (...)
    ],
    "schemaVersion": 1,
    "signatures": [{
        "header": { (...) },
        "signature": "PwuBjXLvQE_DtF29YtyJF2N-zHkVGRh93It4zxL1Igtoi093ykMvXBL_0J6E6-eQVeYrXm3IdDAll-922zeYzQ",
        "protected": "eyJmb3JtYXRMZW5ndGgiOjIwOTk0LCJmb3JtYXRUYWlsIjoiQ24wIiwidGltZSI6IjIwMTUtMTItMDdUMTM6NDE6MjJaIn0"
    }]
}
```

Then compare the `fsLayers` array. If it is equal between the two manifests, then building a container based on any of these tags will give the same results (i.e. they point to the same thing).

If you have the images locally, comparing the `imageId` (via `docker inspect` for each tag) is enough and easier. But I don't think that this id can be obtained from the registry.